# Kivy ScreenManager Errors

Tags: python, kivy

I'm a beginner with kivy language. I'm writing an app but I have some difficulties. My app is going to consist of a few screens so I decided to use the ScreenManager but each time I'm trying to launch the .py I get an error and this makes the python not responding. I have saved both the .py file and the .kv file in the same folder.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Eng. Aladdin Hammodi\Desktop\kivy\main.py", line 15, in <module>
     presentation = Builder.load_file(Aladdin.kv)
 NameError: name 'Aladdin' is not defined
```

Python file:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder

presentation = Builder.load_file(Aladdin.kv)


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class AladdinApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

sample_app = AladdinApp()
sample_app.run()
```

aladdin.kv

```
<ScreenOne>:
    name:screen1

    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            source:'image1'
        Label:
            text:'Hello\n Welcome to my app\n'
            font_size: 40

        Button:
            text: 'Next'
            pos: 0,1
            font_size:20
            hint_size:0.1,0.05
            on_press:root.manager.current='screen2'
<ScreenTwo>:
    name:screen2
    FloatLayout:
       canvas:
            source:'image1'
        Label:
            text:'Please insert your name'
            text:'Please insert your Password'
            font_size: 40

        Button:
            text: 'Next'
            pos: 0,1
            font_size:20
            hint_size:0.1,0.05
            on_press:root.manager.current='screen1'
```

Comment: If you think a question answers your problem, please activate the checkmark next to the answer to give credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```
presentation = Builder.load_file(Aladdin.kv)
```

`Aladdin` is interpreted as the variable. If you want to pass a string to the method, call it like:

```
presentation = Builder.load_file("Aladdin.kv")
```

Comment: thx a lot 
still having some errors with the app
can you please tell me where are my errors 
am i wrote the code write or wrong

Comment: i actually want each screen to have a background which is image1.jpg 
and want to have some text in this screen
and a button to move to the other screen

Comment: Basically, we are not a * make code for me* service. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), including the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: im sorry im didnt mean it like * make code for me* , im stuck with this and cant go further and cant find any one to help me thats why i asked you 
thx again

Answer (score 1):

The files had a couple of issues:

1. @Artur R. Czechowski already pointed out missing quotation marks `Builder.load_file('Aladdin.kv')`
2. you did not define a root widget in the kv file or in your python code. I changed this by returning it in the build method `def build(self): return ScreenManager()`
3. it is not `hint_size`, correct is `size_hint`
4. I think you tried having an image as background. This is one way of doing it, do not forget the file ending e.g. `.jpg`

---

```
canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size: self.size
                source:'image1.jpg'
```

As a side note: It makes sense to build your app step by step. Write as little code as possible which works and then check. Write some more code, check again. Happy coding with kivy :).

### python code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder

#### in comment requested to also make cursor visible and not full screen ####
from kivy.config import Config 
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')
Config.set('graphics','show_cursor','1')
####

Builder.load_file('Aladdin.kv')


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class AladdinApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManager()

AladdinApp().run()
```

### revised kv file:

```
<ScreenManager>:
    ScreenOne:
    ScreenTwo:

<ScreenOne>:
    name:'screen1'

    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size: self.size
                source:'image1.jpg'
        Label:
            text:'Hello\n Welcome to my app\n'
            font_size: 40

        Button:
            text: 'Next'
            pos: 0,1
            font_size:20
            size_hint:0.1,0.05
            on_press:root.manager.current='screen2'
<ScreenTwo>:
    name:'screen2'
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size: self.size
                source:'image1.jpg'
        Label:
            text:'Please insert your name'
            #text:'Please insert your Password'
            font_size: 40

        Button:
            text: 'Next'
            pos: 0,1
            font_size:20
            size_hint:0.1,0.05
            on_press:root.manager.current='screen1'
```

Comment: thx a lot, actually i figured out what was wrong with my code but now there is something else that dose not work 
firstly: the window fits in the whole screen and i cant resize it like i used to do before
second, i cant point with my mouse on the window in order to click on the next button

Comment: @aladdinhammodi    Are you using a raspberry Pi? On windows I can see my mouse on windows and it does not fill the whole screen.

Comment: no im not using it 
i cant see the mouse at all and even if i clicked on the window i cant see any thing. if i click right click on the mouse i can see red spots (like when im using the scatter)

Comment: What are you using? I remember needing to edit some config file on the raspberry pi...

Comment: i also tried to do like this
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '200')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '200')

and like this 
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (300, 100) 
but still fits on the whole screen

Comment: actually im working on my final project for college and its a android app the unlock the mobile by recognizing the face. i havent inserted any python file of the recognition coed i just tried the ScreenManager

Comment: are you on windows, linux, android, ios?

Comment: im on windows and my laptop is new with i7 processor and 16GB ram and intelgraphics 620 hd screen card

Comment: from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0') maybe try adding these lines after Builder.load_file('Aladdin.kv') Tell me if it works.

Comment: thx a lot this is working now. but still cant see my mouse when i point on something in the window

Comment: Config.set('graphics','show_cursor','1') try adding this below what you just added. Does it work? Try also without '' Config.set('graphics','show_cursor',1)

Comment: yeah :D i really appreciate your help i cant thank you enough you saved me 
thx again 
is it ok if i keep in touch with you if i have any other  problems in the future with my app. actually i couldn't find any one to help me figure out my errors

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Happy that I could help you, if you need more help, just post another question and post a link to the question here below, so that i get notified. An upvote and or accepting my answer would really be appreciated, but this is up to you.

Comment: i have another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598191/inserting-a-python-script-in-a-class-in-kivy