# How to insert a Python script in a class in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a python text that I want to put in a class in kivy. Then I would like to use this class as a function and call it from another class. How should I define the class? What should I write in the brackets `class FaceGenerator()`?

```
class FaceGenerator():
    # open the camera and capture video
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    face_detector = 
    cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    # Asking the user for an ID and Name
    ID = raw_input('Please insert your ID number  ')
    Name= raw_input('Please insert your Name  ')
    sample_number = 0 # a counter that counts the number of pictures for 
    each person in the database

    # detecting the face and draw rectangle on it
    while (True):
        retval,image = cam.read() # reading image from cam
        print np.shape(image)
        gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # converting 
        image to gray image
        faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray_image,1.3,5)
        ''' detectMultiScale, detects objects of different sizes in the 
        input image.
        the detected objects are returned as a list of rectangles
        '''
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
            sample_number=sample_number+1
        # saving the captured face in the facebase folder
            cv2.imwrite('Trainer/User.'+ID+'.'+str(sample_number)+'.jpg', 
         gray_image[y:y+h,x:x+w])
    # this loop drawing a rectabgle on the face while the cam is open 
        cv2.imshow('frame',image)
        if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        elif sample_number==20:
            break

    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return Label(text = "Succesfully created trainning set")
```

Comment: Write in brackets object, --> class FaceGenerator(object). But what you are defining is not really a class. I think you would be better served by just defining a function which you can call from anywhere in your program def FaceGenerator ():

Comment: I would just define a function which returns a string and then update this by going through your widget tree and updating the text property of a label not returning a new label.

Comment: I think following [these trivial rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) could make your posts much better with only a little work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a class put `object` in brackets --> `class FaceGenerator(object):`  But in your case there is simply no need for a class, what you are looking for is a function. If I understand it correctly you only want to call one function on that class so you could just only define a function in the first place

**Here is one way of doing what I think you would like to do:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


def FaceGenerator():
    #do your stuff
    face = 'PalimPalim'
    return face

Builder.load_string("""
<rootwi>:
    label_to_be_changed: label_to_be_changed
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text:'klick me'
        on_press: root.change_Label_text()
    Label:
        id: label_to_be_changed

""")
class rootwi(BoxLayout):
    label_to_be_changed = ObjectProperty()

    def change_Label_text(self):
        temp_str = FaceGenerator()
        self.label_to_be_changed.text = temp_str

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return rootwi()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**some more Infos**

- root in the kv refers to the left most widget in this case `rootwi`
- Defining an ObjectProperty for a widget which is part of a widget is
  my favorite way of doing any updating of properties. There are for sure other ways.

Comment: Actually what I want to do is inserting the FaceRecognition code to one of the screen in my kivy app, and when I press a button I would like to start using this coed to generate a training data base so when I call the recognizer, it will use this training data base to get the face features and recognize the face. I want to put this code in a rectangle so when its done capturing the pictures I can press a button in the right bottom corner to move to the next page.

Comment: So i should define a function then in the kv code on the specific screen I have to put BoxLayout and in this BoxLayout I should call the function, am I write?

Comment: you can define the function independent of your screen and just call or reference it on the screen. In the example I provided FaceGenerator function is not related to kv or a class. I am just calling it in a class.

Comment: I am calling the function and use the result to change a property of a widget. same can be done for your screen. call the function and use the result to update sth on your screen for example the text property of one of your screens label.

Comment: Alright, I will try this and let you know what happened with me. 
Thanks

Comment: I can't see any function call where is it? Can you post a new question or edit this one so that I can see the whole code.

Comment: I defined the function as you told me. In the FloatLAyout, i did like this 
    FloatLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            FaceRecognition()
When i run the code i get an error: invalid class name

Comment: Here I used the BoxLayout, so when I want to start the function I don't want the camera to fit the whole screen, I must define a position and a size for the box

Comment: If you follow the structure in my answer, it must work. without seeing the whole code I cannot help you. Have you looked at the answer I provided? Take the time to make your code available via a question. I took probably 20 mins to make the answer above and have not received anything for that. I think it is more than fine for you to take the time to at least make your code available in a readable format.

Comment: I will do it now, I'm sorry I haven't worked on my project for a few days that why I haven't replied to you.

Comment: I have replied with an answer below

Answer (score 0):

@PalimPalim I worked as your structure above. My code is now like this 
Python code

```
import kivy
import cv2, os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')
Config.set('graphics','show_cursor','1')

def FaceGenerator():
# open the camera and capture video
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    face_detector = 
    cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    ID = 0
    sample_number = 0 # a counter that counts the number of pictures for 
    each person in the database

    # detecting the face and draw rectangle on it
    while (True):
        retval,image = cam.read() # reading image from cam
        print np.shape(image)
        gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # converting 
        image to gray image
        faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray_image,1.3,5)
        ''' detectMultiScale, detects objects of different sizes in the 
        input image.
        the detected objects are returned as a list of rectangles
        '''
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,0), 2)
            sample_number=sample_number+1
        # saving the captured face in the facebase folder

            cv2.imwrite('Trainer/User.'+str(ID)+'.'+str(sample_number)+'.jpg',
            gray_image[y:y+h,x:x+w])
    # this loop drawing a rectabgle on the face while the cam is open 
        cv2.imshow('frame',image)
        if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        elif sample_number==20:
            break

    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    output = "Succesfully created trainning set"
    return output

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenThree(Screen):
        pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


sm = Builder.load_file("facerecognition.kv")

class FaceRecognitionApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__=="__main__":
    FaceRecognitionApp().run()
```

The .KV file is:

```
ScreenManagement:
    id: screen_management
    ScreenOne:
    ScreenTwo:
    ScreenThree:



<ScreenOne>:
    name: "screen1"
    id: screen_one

    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                source: "image1.jpg"
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size

        Label:
            text:"Hello\n Welcome to my App\n"
            font_size:40 
            color: 0,0,0,1
        Button:
            text: 'Next'
            font_size: 32 # font size
            size_hint: .2,.1
            pos_hint:{'right':1, 'y':0}
            on_release: app.root.current="screen2"

<ScreenTwo>:
    name: "screen2"
    id: screen_two

    FloatLayout:
        canvas:

            Rectangle:
                source: "image1.jpg"
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size

        Label:
            text:"Please insert your Name\n Please insert your Password\n"
            font_size:40 
            color: 0,0,0,1
        Button:
            text: 'Next'
            font_size: 32 # font size
            size_hint: .2,.1
            pos_hint:{'right':1, 'y':0}
            on_release: app.root.current="screen3"

<ScreenThree>:
    name: "screen3"
    id: screen_three


    FloatLayout:
        canvas:

            Rectangle:
                source: "image1.jpg"
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size


        Button:
            text: 'Next'
            font_size: 32 # font size
            size_hint: .2,.1
            pos_hint:{'right':1, 'y':0}
            on_release: app.root.current="screen1"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            FaceGenerator()
```

Comment: BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            FaceGenerator()  won't work, because you need some button or so which calls your function when called.

Comment: Furthermore, kivy stops updating while another function is running, so you might have to look into threading https://stackoverflow.com/a/44605996/6646710

Comment: What if I added a button in the BoxLayout and when I press on it, it opens the function and starts taking some photos. Can I do  on_release: app.root.current= "FaceGenerator"

Comment: this is still not a call to the function. do sth like  on_release: app.root.fg() and add to your app class a method def fg(self): FaceGenerator()

Comment: you mean do it like this, 
class FaceRecognitionApp(App):
    def fg(self):
        FaceGenerator()
    def build(self):
        return sm

Comment: i did like this. but when i click on the button i get an error  AttributeError: 'ScreenManagement' object has no attribute 'fg'

Comment: try app.fg(), or just on_release:FaceGenerator()

Comment: on_release: app.fg() , this almost worked. what I mean is, I see that my cam is working now but actually, the I can't see my face on the screen and it seems to be like the cam is entering an infinite loop because when I touch any other place on the screen the kivy not responding

Comment: that is what I meant with my threading comment stackoverflow.com/a/44605996/6646710 What does your function FaceGenerator() do if you call it without the kivy

Comment: I haven't worked with Thread before, I will read abut it and try to understand it.

Comment: Actually, I figured out that I had some extra lines that I don't need. First, in the function, i don't need " ID = raw_input('Please insert your ID number  ')
    Name= raw_input('Please insert your Name  ') ."  Now I had to set the ID = 0, because I'm not making an SQLite database, i used this before to create a database. Second, I didn't copy the cascade file to the same directory. But now when I run the code I get this error cv2.imwrite('Trainer/User.'+ID+'.'+str(sample_number)+'.jpg',gray_image[y:y+h,x:x+w])
 TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: cv2.imwrite('Trainer/User.'+str(ID)+'.'+str(sample_number)+'.jpg'‌​,gray_image[y:y+h,x:‌​x+w])  . My error was that i should read the ID as a string, i add str(ID) and its working now

Comment: But, when the cam starts capturing pictures, an external window is open and I don't want this external window, I want to open in in the screen. So I should use the Thread in order to make this?

Comment: No threading won't help with that. I don't think this is possible. You would need to base whatever produces this image in kivy. I don't think that is worth trying.

Comment: So, when I do this on my phone it actually will open another window take some pictures and then will close and back to the app screen.

Comment: I am not sure if this would ever work on your phone. Have you tried including all these python libraries in an android apk. Is this even possible? I don't know. I would try that first.

Comment: In order to do that, I need a Linux system, and I work on windows. I will finish everything I'm working on and then try it on android apk

Comment: no, you do not need a linux system. there is an image for a virtual machine on kivy's website. the image has everything setup for you.

Comment: Hello, my friend, I have another question can you help me with that?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44782303/kivy-the-best-way-to-set-username-and-password-for-the-app?noredirect=1#comment76545437_44782303

Comment: I am busy, but I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: @PalimPalim can you help me with this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836370/kivy-running-the-app-automatically-when-slide-to-unlock-the-phone