# Kivy: Running the App Automatically When Slide To Unlock the Phone

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy

I'm building an Android App, using Kivy and Python 2.7, which is going to unlock the phone based on Face Recognition. After downloading the App and initializing it, I would like the App to be opened directly when **Slide To Unlock** the phone, open a specific screen **"The Recognizer Screen**, recognize my face and then **Unlock** the phone.
What should I add to the .KV code or even to the .py code to root the **Slide To Unlock** to my app?
For example, if this is my .KV code

```
<ScreenFour>:
name: "screen4"
id: screen_four


FloatLayout:
    canvas:

        Rectangle:
            source: "image1.jpg"
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size


    Button:
        text: 'Next'
        font_size: 32 # font size
        size_hint: .2,.1
        pos_hint:{'right':1, 'y':0}
        on_release: app.root.current="screen5"



    Button:
        text: "Unlock the phone"
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint:{'right':0.5, 'y':0.5}
        size_hint: 0.4,0.2
        on_release: app.fr()
```

where `one_release: app.fr()` is the root to start the FaceRecognizer code 
What do I have to add to this code? Or do I have to add any thing to the Python code on the specific

```
class ScreenFour(Screen):
    pass
```

Or do I have to add it here:

```
class FaceRecognitionApp(App):
    def fg(self):
        FaceGenerator()
    def fr(self):
        FaceRecognizer()  
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__=="__main__":
    FaceRecognitionApp().run()
```

I would really appreciate having an answer, I'm working on a project and I'm running out of time.

Comment: for interfacing with android u could use https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius This is quite advanced stuff and I am not sure if there is anything for the unlock screen

Comment: **root the Slide To Unlock to my app** I don't think and actually hope that sth like this is not possible through an app in android since it would have major security issues. You could build an alternative lock screen in your app. One different from the actual android lock screen, as part of your app.

Comment: What do you mean with building an alternative lock screen?

Comment: A screen inside you kivy app which provides the same functionality as a lock screen

Comment: So, you say I have to build the alternative lock screen, and in this lock screen I should put my recognizer code or even password, then when I run the app on my phone this alternative screen will be the lock screen of the phone

Comment: how do I do the alternative lock screen, Is it only with Java?  I can't find any way on the internet to do it with Kivy. I'm not familiar with java

Comment: No I mean just a kivy screen which acts like the lock screen.

Comment: when I make this lock screen, how can I call this screen right when I unlock the phone?

Comment: you can't. I cannot think of any way how you could do anything right after the lock screen. Even with pyjinius this probably won't be possible

Comment: but you could design it as a proof of concept, just to show, that your facial recognition works

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Thank you

Comment: Hello, @PalimPalim I've posted a new question can you help me with it, I'm sorry if I keep annoying you but I'm  running out off time and without the code I can't finish my  project
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44862551/python-valueerror-all-the-input-array-dimensions-except-for-the-concatenation

Comment: `return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)` If I understand the traceback correctly, you are passing in sth which has different dimensions than the rest of what you are passing in. I have actually never worked with numpy I don't think I can be of much help therefore...

Comment: Alright, I'm trying to solve it. I will let you know. Thanks again

Comment: @PalimPalim, I get this error because of a function called asColoumnMatrix(X)  that  Creates a column-matrix from multi-dimensional data items in list l.  
X [list] List with multi-dimensional data. 
my images wich is converted to X[list] are put in a folder with one subfolder, so I think my X is not a multi-dimensional matrix

Comment: sorry, don't know how to help you. I would suggest splitting your code in smaller parts and making them work seperately. did you write all the code yourself or is this sth adapted from somewhere else? if so might make sense to include source. if you have smaller parts it might also be easier to get answers for your questions on stackoverflow. i think your question is too long. most people probably see it and do not read it beasue it is so much text

Comment: but bottom line i don't really know how to help, i would if i could...